# How to render multiple templates using #each in a handlebars?

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have one array of objects inside this objects I have some list of id's and using this id's I have to render multiple templates using #each loop for handlebars.

Simple this statement will return me the list of containing names of template.

```
{{#each data in sections1}}
{{data.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Output :

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X

Consider this all A to Z are different template names respectively
Now I'm trying to render all these templates using #each loop in handlebar But I don't know the exact syntax.

For example can we do like this way ?

```
{{#each data in sections1}}
{{render data.id}} //Here I'm getting error Because of it is not exact syntax
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider using partials, naming them with the proper name based on `data.id` value. Then use them like: `{{partial data.id}}`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rowuxe/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: It's returning me error like "Assertion Failed: Unable to find partial with name 'info'.". Here Info is a one of the id from data.id array

Comment: That's because you have to create a template with the name info.hbs inside templates folder. You can read more about partials [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/rendering-with-helpers/). Hope that helps...

Comment: Also if you are using ember-cli don't forget to put a dash in front of partial name (e.g templates/-info.hbs).

Comment: No I have build version of ember

Comment: .hbs is compulsory ? If I have something like this way so what ? <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="info">
        <div id="content_fire"></div></script> as a info.html then it is working ?

Comment: And also I have already created the the html files for all these sections inside  template folder but I am not getting any output

Comment: Ok then try this: `data-template-name='_info'>` for template name.

Comment: You don't have to create multiple html files. Is there any particular reason your are doing this?

Comment: Yes it is different small modules that displays different things inside

Comment: If I have to create this templates using each then any way ?

Comment: You don't have to create multiple html files. only multiple partials as described before, inside your main index.html.

Comment: Ok So i have to create multiple partials inside index.html like 
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="info"></script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="fire"></script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="land"></script>
etc.. ?

Comment: Yes. You missed underscore in partials names. See an [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rowuxe/1/)